# Adding a comma to the end of each values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame as following,

```
 df.head()
    col1 col2 col3  col4     col5
    a.    34  67 34,44,55  41,54,67
    b.    75   105  75,90   85 105
```

And I need to add a comma after all elements or values in `col4` and `col5`. At the end, I am looking for a data frame like this,

```
 df.head()
    col1 col2 col3  col4     col5
    a.    34  67 34,44,55,  41,54,67,
    b.    75   105  75,90,  85 105,
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: `df['col4'] += ','`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `lambda` function just to append a `,` to the columns you need.

```
df[<column>] = df[<column>].apply(lambda x: str(x)+',')
```

This also converts each of the columns intended to a string so that you will not have issues appending to only `int` fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can change them like this:

```
df[['col4', 'col5']] += (',', ',')
```